# Get Most Recent Employer using Facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I get the most recent employer for a logged in user using the Graph API? I know I can find all listed employers using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendlists/work
```

And I can use the returned number from the 'id' field and tack on '/members' to get the members of that group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$config = array(
'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
'secret' => FB_SECRET_KEY,
'cookie' => true // enable optional cookie support  
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config); 
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array(
'scope' => 'user_work_history',
'redirect_uri' => FB_APP_URL,
);


$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params); 

if ($user) {
  try { 
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    var_dump($user_profile["work"][0]["employer"]["name"]); //will display most recent eployer

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}
else
{
?>
    <script>top.location.href = "<?php echo $loginUrl?>";
<?php

}
```

?>

Comment: Sorry Madan, this is for iOS, not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality appears to be provided at user endpoint using additional parameters concordant with your search.

For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=work
```

From [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/):

- `work`: A list of the user's work history

  - Permission tokens: `user_work_history` or `friends_work_history`
  - Returns: array of objects containing employer, location, position, start_date and end_date fields

You can reasonably find the user's current employer by inspecting the `start_date` and `end_date` respectively. For a different user than the current user, replace `me` with the desired `PROFILE_ID`.

Comment: I had thought about doing this, but I was wondering if there was a more automatic way. It just seemed like there should be a way to order the work history items by date on their end.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Agreed. This is the best way I can currently find according to their API, but if someone finds a better way, they're more than welcome to answer and grab the bounty. :)